# Erro para instalação do Postgresql no mint 19

Tags: postgresql, linux, instalador, mint, dependências

Estou tentando realizar a instalação do posgresql no mint 19 quando recebi um erro de dependência, fazendo algumas pesquisas descobrir que poderia tentar o comando **dpkg --configure -a**, porém recebi o seguinte erro:

```
 libc6-dbg:amd64 depende de libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2); porém:
  Versão de libc6:amd64 no sistema é 2.31-0ubuntu9.1.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote libc6-dbg:amd64 (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de libc6-dev:amd64:
 libc6-dev:amd64 depende de libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2); porém:
  Versão de libc6:amd64 no sistema é 2.31-0ubuntu9.1.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote libc6-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
 libc6-dbg:amd64
 libc6-dev:amd64
```

Para resolver tentei  o comando **sudo apt-get install r-base**, que gerou o erro:

```
 libc6-dev : Depende: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) mas 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 está para ser instalado
 r-base : Depende: r-base-core (>= 3.6.3-2) mas não será instalado
          Depende: r-recommended (= 3.6.3-2) mas não será instalado
          Recomenda: r-base-html mas não será instalado
          Recomenda: r-doc-html mas não será instalado
```

Pesquisando um pouco mais tentei resolver o erro acima com o comando **sudo apt-get install -f** porém recebi o seguinte erro:

```
(Lendo banco de dados ... 316581 ficheiros e directórios actualmente instalados.)
A preparar para desempacotar .../libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_amd64.deb ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: erro ao processar o arquivo /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 o subprocesso do pacote libc6:amd64, novo script pre-installation retornou erro do status de saída 1
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Não  tenho muita habilidade com Linux, é a primeira vez que utilizo e realmente não sei mais o que fazer para tentar resolver isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um processo estava bloqueando qualquer comando para atualizar ou instalar pacotes, depois de pesquisar encontrei o comando:

> sudo fuser -v ​/var/cache/debconf/config.dat

Esse comando mostra quais processos estavam me impedindo de dar o comando , **sudo apt-get install -f**, e de instalar e atualizar novos pacotes.

Depois disso foi só dar o comando para "matar" o/os processo/processos que estava impedindo de seguir.

> sudo kill PID

Esses passos resolveram meus problemas com dependências e pacotes no mint.